# Delay first transition in nivo slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

Got 2 nivo sliders working on the same page from 2 separate js's (i need it to work from 2 separate js's).

How can i delay first transition for one of them? Been looking all over the internet for a working solution, but for the most part people only tell how to change animation speed. I need speed to be equal for both of sliders, yet one of them starting a little bit later than other.

Trying to delay it this way, but it doesn't work

```
jQuery('#slider2').nivoSlider2()    
                  .delay(3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
jQuery('#slider2').nivoSlider();
jQuery('#slider2').data('nivoslider').stop();
setTimeout(function() { 
        jQuery('#slider2').data('nivoslider').start();
    }, 
    10000);
```

Comment: It delays slider load. I need slider to load immediately, but the first transition delayed. Thanks though.

Comment: Nilesh,you already test?why you said that.I already edit code when user3594249 said no ok. I tested it worked ok i have live page working ok this case http://travelkey.vn/Deafault3.html???